# How to add non-duplicate items to a list box from a string array

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

With the help of Google and a bit of luck, I was able to write code which adds a string array to a list box and displays the duplicate total in a text box using LINQ. I now need to be able to read from the array and only display non-duplicate items in a second listbox.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] MyStringArray = new string[20];

    MyStringArray[0] = "Apple";
    MyStringArray[1] = "Green";
    MyStringArray[2] = "Apple";
    MyStringArray[3] = "Red";
    MyStringArray[4] = "Orange";
    MyStringArray[5] = "Orange";
    MyStringArray[6] = "Bananas";
    MyStringArray[7] = "Yellow";
    MyStringArray[8] = "Mango";
    MyStringArray[9] = "Yellow";
    MyStringArray[10] = "Cherry";
    MyStringArray[11] = "Red";
    MyStringArray[12] = "Fig";
    MyStringArray[13] = "Brown";
    MyStringArray[14] = "Fig";
    MyStringArray[15] = "Brown";
    MyStringArray[16] = "Fig";
    MyStringArray[17] = "Orange";
    MyStringArray[18] = "Brown";
    MyStringArray[19] = "Cranberry";

    lstbDup.Items.AddRange(MyStringArray);

    List<string> dups = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < MyStringArray.Length; i++)
    {
        string current = MyStringArray[i];
        if (MyStringArray.Count(s => s == current) > 1 &&
            !dups.Contains(current))
        {
            dups.Add(current);
        }
    }
    txtdupdisp.Text += dups.Count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for distinct items or non duplicates?

Answer (score 5):

Use LINQ's [`.Distinct()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436.aspx) operator to remove duplicate items from a sequence:

```
var uniques = MyStringArray.Distinct().ToList();
foreach(string s in uniques)
    yourSecondListBox.Items.Add(s);
```

Or simply

```
yourSecondListBox.Items.AddRange(MyStringArray.Distinct().ToArray());
```

However as stated by another answer, your question is not clear. The code above retrieves every string that appears at least one time in your array. This means that also the word 'Apple' (it appears 2 times) will be included in the second listbox.
Instead, if you want only the items that appears just one time then the answer from [vc 74](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446279/vc-74) is the correct one albeit a more compact version exists:

```
List<string> nonDuplicates = MyStringArray.GroupBy(x => x)
                                          .Where(group => group.Count()==1)
                                          .SelectMany(group => group).ToList();
```

Linq is really funny and it seems that it gives infinite ways to skin the cat.

Comment: Does the OP want the distinct items or just the non duplicates?

Comment: @vc74: Good question. Probably we ought to ask the OP that.

Comment: Ah, that's subtle. However, looking at the actual code it seems that he wants all the items with count > 1. A logical error? An incomplete code? Yes we need an explanation from the OP.

Comment: @Steve I think he wants to build 2 collections, 1 with the duplicates (count > 1) and 1 with the non duplicates (count = 1)

Comment: Let's see. In that case your solution is the correct one. Just fix that `group.Count` to `group.Count()`

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the non duplicates:

```
var groups = MyStringArray.ToLookup(str => str);
List<string> nonDuplicates = groups.Where(group => (group.Count() == 1)).
                                    Select(group => group.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: @stakx Maybe I misunderstood the OP, I thought he was looking for the non duplicates, i.e. the items present only once in the list. Distinct would return all the unique items, even the ones with duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

```
 List<string> list = MyStringArray.Cast<string>().Distinct().ToList();
```

Once you get the filtered data bind this list to your control.

```
listBox1.DataSource = list;
```